# Concatenate data frames of different shapes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

How do it concatenate data frames of two different shapes?

My ultimate objective is to combine 7 different data frames and then export to csv so that all the 7 data frames can be viewed in a single file.

Note: All the dataframes have different headers.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), columns= ['X' , 'Y'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns= ['M', 'N', 'O'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns= ['J', 'K', 'L'])
```

Pandas concatenate would give me the following results.
[image: result using concatenate]

I am expecting the output to be in the following format in a single csv file.
[image]

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: You should add input and expected output.  And include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific.  I was expecting some sort of generic answer.  Anyways, I have added more details what I did and what I could not obtain in the results.

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're trying to 'flaten' the data set, I think it'd make the most sense to merge about the axis:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 4), columns= ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 2), columns= ['X' , 'Y'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns= ['M', 'N', 'O'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), columns= ['J', 'K', 'L'])

print(pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4],axis=1))
```